# How to find the first matching list value from sequence using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let us say we have a list and sequence:

`a_list = ["abcd", "abc", "ab" , "a"]`

`sequence = "ihavejustlearnedmyabcs"`

I need help writing a program that finds the first matching value on the list in the sequence. Like it will iterate through the list and the sequence to see if any of the values will match. I have written a program but I feel it only works for true/false values:

```
if a_list in sequence: 
    return #this is the area I need help with
```

However I more need the output to return the matching value. In this case the return would be "abc", because it is the first string in the list that matches the sequence. It does not have to be a 'if-in' situation, but that is just the one I found I needed help with. Please let me know if you would like me to clarify any more details. I would greatly appreciate any help/guidance!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is take your list of strings in `a_list`, and iterate through them and return the string if it is found in `sequence`. Since you only want the first occurrence, you can then use `break` to stop the loop.

```
a_list = ["abcd", "abc", "ab" , "a"]
sequence = "ihavejustlearnedmyabcs"

for x in a_list:
    if x in sequence:
        print(x)
        break
    else:
        continue
```